# How can I run a python script in a web server (nodeJS) after pressing a button on frontend?

Tags: javascript, python, html, node.js, web-scraping

Well, straight to the point, I have a python script that, after a given URL, scrapes data from a certain website and creates an excel sheet, also, I have a running web server that I made for a user.
How can I run that python script on my backend after inputting the website URL to be **scraped** in the frontend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Node.js to create an http server to receive requests from the front end, and then send a request to the server to execute the script when the front end presses the button.

For how to create an http server, you can take a look at express:
https://expressjs.com/

And then you can use `child_process` to run python script. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html